# Why doesn't Razor syntax inside a code block dereference properly?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have the following markup in a Razor view:

```html
<@Model.HeadingName>
  @Model.HeadingText
</@Model.HeadingName>
```

This works great and ends up rendering something like this:

```html
<h2>
  Contact Us
</h2>
```

However, if I want to check for null, it fails to render the closing tag:

```html
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.HeadingName))
{
  <@Model.HeadingName>
    @Model.HeadingText
  </@Model.HeadingName>
}
```

For some reason, that results in the following output:

```html
<h2>
  Contact Us
<!--@Model.HeadingName-->
```

Does anyone know how to dereference that closing block so it renders properly?

## Things I've tried unsuccessfully

- Using `@:` to start the line
- Adding a space in the closing tag

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get it to dereference properly, either. Unfortunately, it seems that in order to transition back into HTML, Razor expects to see an HTML tag name in plain text. Although you can add attributes to tags in this way, so...

...why not make a custom [Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.2), then your Razor would change to something like this:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.HeadingName))
{
    <dynamic type="@Model.HeadingName">
        @Model.HeadingText
    </dynamic>
}
```

To define this tag helper, you just need to create a class that inherits from the `TagHelper` (in this case we create the `DynamicTagHelper` class):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace MyNamespace.TagHelpers
{
    public class DynamicTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public string Type { get; set; } //this must match the attribute

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = Type;    // e.g. replaces <dynamic type="h2"> with <h2>
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to make the DynamicTagHelper class available to all your Razor views, you would add the `addTagHelper` directive to the Views/_ViewImports.cshtml file:

```
@addTagHelper *, MyNamespace
```

(Be sure to replace `MyNamespace` with your actual namespace)

Might be overkill for what you were trying to do, but at least this may inspire you!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use `Html.Raw()` to output the text, though it will look ugly in the view and intellisense may balk at a "missing" closing tag:

```html
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.HeadingName))
{
  <@Model.HeadingName>
    @Model.HeadingText
  @Html.Raw($"</{Model.HeadingName}>")
}
```